# Trimmed down JAXB for just unmarshalling?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

I'm building an application where space is at a premium. I'd really like to use JAXB's unmarshalling capabilities, but including the whole library is out of the question. Has anyone pared it down so that only the bits needed for unmarshalling are included?

Answer (score 1):

Is this for an application running on Java5 or earlier? JAXB is included as part of the Java6 JRE.

I don't think you'll have much luck trimming down JAXB, it wasn't designed for that. You may have better luck with a 3rd-party tool such as [JiBX](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/) or [Castor](http://www.castor.org/), though, which do much the same thing, and may be a bit more lightweight.

Comment: It's running on an alternate JRE... should have mentioned that.